# Is it right using of the word 'like' in the movie Pulp fiction?

Tags: as-like

I found this sentence in the movie *Pulp Fiction*:

> Then why are you trying to fuck him **like** a bitch, Brett?

In this case, I consider the Brett is a bitch

*like+noun*

> Then why are you trying to fuck him **as** a bitch, Brett?

In this case, I consider the Brett is trying to (use) fuck him as a bitch, albeit it sounds weird for me

*as+verb*  ; use as+noun; work as+noun

Comment: Brett is not the bitch. Marcellus (the person being referred to as "him") is.

Comment: We can discuss taboo language on ELL and EL&U, but the site policy is to remove it from question titles.  That helps keep it from popping up on the Hot Network Questions list, among other places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a general idiomatic expression, "to (verb) *like* (something)."  Some examples from popular music:

> Drop it like it's hot
>
> We're going to party like it's 1999
>
> So we put our hands up like the ceiling can't hold us

And many many more.  It's pretty common.

In this particular case, Jules is asking Brett why he is treating Marcellus **as if** Marcellus was his "bitch" (i.e., someone he can do anything he wants to).  This use of "bitch" is also pretty common nowadays, but a full explanation of the nuance is not only too much for a quick answer, but also probably beyond me since I'm too old to be aware of the latest slang.

Watch a lot of Tarentino's movies and cable-TV prison dramas, and you should get a pretty good education, though  :)

Comment: (I've got the) *Moves Like Jagger* is another good example. :-)

Comment: "Party like a rock ... party like a rock star!"